# Automatically wrapping/converting JavaBeans into case classes

Tags: scala

We are using Kryo to communicate between a Scala application and a Java application. Since the class definitions have to be used from Java (and we don't want to include the Scala library as a dependency in the Java applicaton) we are using JavaBeans to define the transfer objects.

However, using JavaBeans directly in Scala is a bit of a hassle. No pattern matching, having to use new, etc. What we're doing right now is defining extractors and apply methods in separate objects on the Scala side to make it nicer to work with these classes.

Since most of what we need is boilerplate, we are wondering if there would be a way of doing this automatically. For example, we have this JavaBean (there are about 20+ different message types):

```
public class HandshakeRequest extends Request {
    private String gatewayId;
    private String requestId;
    private Date timestamp = new Date();

    public HandshakeRequest(String gatewayId, String requestId) {
        this.gatewayId = gatewayId;
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public String getGatewayId() { return gatewayId; }
    public String getRequestId() { return requestId; }
    public Date getTimestamp() { return timestamp; }
    private HandshakeRequest() { /* For Kryo */ }
}
```

This is an example of the object we use to bridge to Scala:

```
object Handshake {
  def unapply(msg: HandshakeRequest): Option[ (DateTime, String, String) ] = {
    (
      new DateTime(msg.getTimestamp.getTime),
      msg.getRequestId,
      msg.getGatewayId
    ).some
  }

  def apply(gatewayId: String, requestId: String) = new HandshakeRequest(gatewayId, requestId)
}
```

Since all of our object have the Timestamp, it is also part of the boilerplate. We'd like some way (perhaps a macro?) to automatically generate the unapply and apply methods (and ideally, the whole object itself).

Does anyone know of an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there were no answers, I came up with this: https://github.com/yetu/scala-beanutils.

Answer (score 3):

I've started a project https://github.com/limansky/beanpuree which allows convertions from beans to case classes. I'm going to add some more features, like automatic type convertion between Java number classes and Scala classes.